# Overlap User Login in Two Projects with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-identity-2

I have a problem I can not understand in asp.net identity

apply the following steps

1. create two empty web projects, they have names :

   - WebApplication1
   - WebApplication2
2. install package "**Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples 2.0.0-beta2**" On each project
3. Create two sql database have the following names:

   - WebDatabase1
   - WebDatabase2
4. add user has name "**User1**" in **WebApplication1**
5. add user has name "**User2**" in **WebApplication2**
6. run two the projects at the **same time**.

My problem is when I Login by "**User1**" in "**WebApplication1**"

I find **WebApplication2** is logged with **User1**.

despite each project have separate database.

And also **NO User1** in **WebApplication2**.

What's a problem?

Excuse my bad English!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a user signs into the site, the auth middleware serializes the logged in user information (including the id, name, and roles) into the encrypted auth cookie. On subsequent visits, the framework simply decrypts and reads that information without hitting the database.

By default, the same cookie name is used across ASP.NET applications. What you see happening is WebApp1 setting the cookie, and WebApp2 reading it. This is because they're on the same domain (or localhost) and cookies are shared across resources on the same domain.

Try changing the cookie name in your applications...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ...
    CookieName = "WebApp1AuthCookie"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose cookie's name for authentication in **web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" name="XXXX_MYNAME_AUTH" />
</authentication>
```

This will avoid overlap by applications when debugging.