# ASP.NET identity two sites, one database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have two sites based on ASP.NET MVC 5. For authorization I use ASP.NET Identity.
Now I want to use one database with user data. These authorizations have one site to fit another site.

If I connect the two sites into one database then the authorization on one site user automatically authorizes and on another site. So do not be.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you don't share the cookie (try to set cookie's name for each app):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "WebApp1AuthCookie"
});
```

These links may help:

[Overlap User Login in Two Projects with ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030102/overlap-user-login-in-two-projects-with-asp-net-identity)

[Asp.Net Identity and cookie names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038303/asp-net-identity-and-cookie-names)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to encapsulate your identity and authorization logic in a web service or in another type of service that can be used by both sites.