# Running two projects from VS2013 on same PC causes login details to be shared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, authentication, session-cookies

I have a very weird issue. I'm currently running two MVC projects on my PC, each on a different port.

If I login to the one app, then the other app also tries to login with the same credentials. Even though those credentials don't exist on the second project, it looks like I'm logged in.

I'm guessing this is a cookie issue? But I have no idea how to solve this.
I want to open each project's home page and login separately into each application with its own credentials.

Comment: This question can be flagged as duplicate...

I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030102/overlap-user-login-in-two-projects-with-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session for user handling, you will be getting this kind of issue. try to launch the second project in incognito mode in the browser.