# auth identity user between multiple project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identity

I'm having a problem right now with ASP MVC 5 Identity.

**Description:**

- I have two projects (*admin* and *website*), the project *admin* is used for Create, read, update and delete operations whereas the project *website* display's content to users.

**I want:**

- When the user logs on project *admin*

  ```
  var user = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //User has value and IsAuthenticated return true.
  ```
- I'm redirecting to the page of project *website* after successful authentication. But, how to get the data user login from project *admin*?

**I have been tried:**

- Create ApiController in project *admin* to get on user login (use RestSharp). But it doesn't work.

  ```
  //function ApiController
  public UserDto GetUser()
  {
      var result = new UserDto();
      var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User; //Can not get user login information
      var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();//Can not get user Id.

      //Map user -> UserDto at here

      return result;
  }
  ```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This post will help you to solve your issue.

[User Login in Two Projects with ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030102/overlap-user-login-in-two-projects-with-asp-net-identity)

You can do this with auth cookie.

Comment: Thank @Karthik. I will try this solution for my problem.